# How do I create a new variable for a group of observations based on another variable specific to that group

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying add a new variable that is based on the observation for one level of a factor within a groups in my dataset. I've been trying to utilize various dplyr functions (`filter`, `select`,`mutate`,`group_by`) but can't figure out how to get them to work together and accomplish my goal.

here is a sample of my data:

```
  rep   rate       n  mort   avg
   <fct> <fct>  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 1     0.747     10     7   0.7
 2 1     0.373     10     7   0.7
 3 1     0.187     10     6   0.6
 4 1     0.0933    10     0   0  
 5 1     0.00      10     1   0.1
 6 2     0.747     10     7   0.7
 7 2     0.373     10     5   0.5
 8 2     0.187     10     1   0.1
 9 2     0.0933    10     4   0.4
10 2     0.00      10     0   0
```

What I'm hoping to accomplish is to create a new variable called `cont` that is derived from the `avg` variable when `rate == "0.00"`. This variable would be the same for each observation within the same `rep` group. The final product would be a table similar to the one below:

```
  rep   rate       n  mort   avg  cont
   <fct> <fct>  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 1     0.747     10     7   0.7  0.1
 2 1     0.373     10     7   0.7  0.1
 3 1     0.187     10     6   0.6  0.1
 4 1     0.0933    10     0   0    0.1
 5 1     0.00      10     1   0.1  0.1
 6 2     0.747     10     7   0.7  0
 7 2     0.373     10     5   0.5  0
 8 2     0.187     10     1   0.1  0
 9 2     0.0933    10     4   0.4  0
10 2     0.00      10     0   0    0
```

I've tried the following code: `data %>% group_by(rep) %>% filter(rate =="0.00") %>% select(avg)` which results in a dataframe with the data that I do want added as the new variable:

```
  rep     avg
  <fct> <dbl>
1 1       0.1
2 2       0  
3 3       0.1
4 4       0.3
5 5       0  
6 6       0  
7 7       0  
8 8       0
```

My problem now is that I have no idea how to create the new variable for each observation within the `rep` group. I'm not sure how to use `mutate` properly in this situation. Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there would be only one occurrence of `rate == "0.00"` in each group, we can do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(rep) %>%
   mutate(cont = avg[rate == "0.00"])

#   rep   rate       n  mort   avg  cont
#  <fct> <fct>  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 1     0.747     10     7   0.7   0.1
# 2 1     0.373     10     7   0.7   0.1
# 3 1     0.187     10     6   0.6   0.1
# 4 1     0.0933    10     0   0     0.1
# 5 1     0.00      10     1   0.1   0.1
# 6 2     0.747     10     7   0.7   0  
# 7 2     0.373     10     5   0.5   0  
# 8 2     0.187     10     1   0.1   0  
# 9 2     0.0933    10     4   0.4   0  
#10 2     0.00      10     0   0     0
```

If there are more than one occurrence, we can use `which.max` to select the first one

```
df %>% group_by(rep) %>% mutate(cont = avg[which.max(rate == "0.00")])
```

---

Using `data.table`, we can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, cont := avg[rate == "0.00"], by = rep]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(rep = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), rate = structure(c(5L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0.00", "0.0933", 
"0.187", "0.373", "0.747"), class = "factor"), n = c(10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), mort = c(7, 7, 6, 0, 
1, 7, 5, 1, 4, 0), avg = c(0.7, 0.7, 0.6, 0, 0.1, 0.7, 0.5, 0.1, 
0.4, 0)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @wolbachia I see, that is strange. Did you get any error or a wrong output? Can you check on the data which I have posted and confirm if it works for you as intended ? Can you also try `kc_scatter %>% group_by(rep) %>% dplyr::mutate(cont = avg[rate == "0.00"])`

Comment: Thank you for the help! Unfortunately neither dplyr approaches worked for me, I'm hoping to figure out why that is. `group_by(rep) %>% mutate(cont = avg[rate == "0.00"])` returned the following: `rep   rate       n  mort   avg  cont
   <fct> <fct>  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 1     0.747     10     7   0.7   0.1
 2 1     0.373     10     7   0.7   0  
 3 1     0.187     10     6   0.6   0.1
 4 1     0.0933    10     0   0     0.3
 5 1     0.00      10     1   0.1   0  
 6 2     0.747     10     7   0.7   0  
 7 2     0.373     10     5   0.5   0  `

Comment: your suggestion addressed the issue! Does that mean another package was masking mutate? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `match`

```
library(dplyr)
df  %>%
   group_by(rep) %>% 
   mutate(cont = avg[match("0.00", rate)])
# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   rep [2]
#   rep   rate       n  mort   avg  cont
#   <fct> <fct>  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 1     0.747     10     7   0.7   0.1
# 2 1     0.373     10     7   0.7   0.1
# 3 1     0.187     10     6   0.6   0.1
# 4 1     0.0933    10     0   0     0.1
# 5 1     0.00      10     1   0.1   0.1
# 6 2     0.747     10     7   0.7   0  
# 7 2     0.373     10     5   0.5   0  
# 8 2     0.187     10     1   0.1   0  
# 9 2     0.0933    10     4   0.4   0  
#10 2     0.00      10     0   0     0
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, cont := avg[match("0.00", rate)], rep]
```

Or using the join as @thelatemail suggested

```
setDT(df)[df[rate=="0.00"], on= .(rep), cont := i.avg]
```

Note; Both the methods would work even if there are duplicate values as `match` returns only the index of the first match.

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(rep = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), rate = structure(c(5L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0.00", "0.0933", 
"0.187", "0.373", "0.747"), class = "factor"), n = c(10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), mort = c(7, 7, 6, 0, 
1, 7, 5, 1, 4, 0), avg = c(0.7, 0.7, 0.6, 0, 0.1, 0.7, 0.5, 0.1, 
0.4, 0)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If going the *data.table* route, you could take advantage of the update join capability - `df[df[rate=="0.00"], on="rep", cont := i.avg]`